# How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized

Tags: java, swing

Ok, this sort of have 2 parts of the question.

1. When I make a `JFrame`, and draw something on it, even if I make the width 400, and make it so that when an item hits it (Allowing for an items width, of course) It bounces back. But it always goes about 10 pixels off the screen for some reason. Is there a way to fix it, or do I just need to compensate by add/subtracting numbers?
2. How can I get the EXACT screen center. So, if I make a `JFrame` which is default as 200*200 pixels, then the center would be 100*100. (Allowing for the problem in question 1) But if someone resizes the screen (and yes, I want them to be able to re-size it) the point is still the center. so if they make it full screen and their screen size is 1200*900, then the center would be 600*450.

I hope this is clear enough

Comment: screen dimensions are always even. you can't get the EXACT center point. LOL

Comment: I presume I'm missing something - but why can't you just do getWidth()/2 getHeight()/2 to find the centre?

Comment: Well that makes me feel stupid... lol

Comment: But the second bit of info, is why does my item go off the screen even though it shouldnt? (As in question 1)

Comment: For question 1: Are you sure you are getting the width of your **drawnig area** and not the width of the **frame**? These may differ.

Comment: WHat i did was make 2 variables, one called height, one called width, and used tyhose while making my JFrame the right size. Then when I drew the ball and all that stuff, I made it so that when it hits the width - 20 (Thats the size of the ball) It bounces back. But instead i needed to compenstate by an aditional 18 pixels

Comment: This might happen because the JFrame size includes menu and different decorators, i.e areas where you cannot draw anything. Not sure about the width part, but for height it is definitely so. The better practice is to create a *drawing area* and draw whatever you want on it. Then just place it on your frame. Then you won't have this kind of trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the sounds of what you are saying, I think you misunderstand what the dimensions of a normal (decorated) frame include.

A `JFrame` consists of a window/frame (normally decorated with a border), a `JRootPane`, which contains a `JLayeredPane` which contains the content pane, `JMenuBar` and glass pane.

[image]

This is, one of the, reasons why you should never override a top level containers `paint` method, because you won't actually be painting within the content/view area.

So, the actual "paintable" region of a frame is it's `width - border.width` x `height - border.height`

[image]

The red line indicates the frame, the blue indicates the content pane.

This raises a very important question, where's the center of the frame?  From the frames perspective, it's 100x100, but from the content pane's perspective, it's 92x81.  Depending on what you want, will depend on which value you will use.  For positioning the frame, you will want to to use the frames center point, for painting, your will want to use the content panes.

Now, the easiest way to center a frame on the screen is simply to call [`Window#setLocationRelativeTo(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) otherwise, I would suggest you use Timr's solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use to centre a `JFrame` on screen, it simply retrieves the height and width of your monitor, then centres  your frame

```
public static void moveToCenterScreen(JFrame frame) {
    Toolkit kit = frame.getToolkit();       
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    Insets in = kit.getScreenInsets(gs[0].getDefaultConfiguration());
    Dimension d = kit.getScreenSize();

    int max_width = (d.width - in.left - in.right);
    int max_height = (d.height - in.top - in.bottom);   

    frame.setLocation((int) (max_width - frame.getWidth()) / 2, (int) (max_height - frame.getHeight() ) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something simple along the lines of

```
int ___ = (Jframe.getWidth())/2
int ___ = (Jframe.getHeight())/2
```

The blank would be the value you want to be at the center point.

As for the other problem, you could have some padding or something that is moving the item around. Not sure without seeing the code for it.

Comment: Unless the frame is undecorated (which is unspecified), frames have borders inset into the bounds of the frame (so that the actually content area is smaller then the width/height of the frame)