# JFrame Background error: Unwanted Transparency

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency, paint

I am having an issue. My JFrame starts with contents inside of it, but displays transparently with the contents on top.

```
package javagame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaGame extends JFrame{

    public JavaGame(){
        setTitle("Java Game");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 250, 250);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new JavaGame();

    }

}
```

Help is appreciated! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things...

## First...

You are breaking the `paint` chain...

```
public void paint (Graphics g){
    // You MUST call super.paint here...
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 250, 250);
}
```

## Second

You should avoid, at all cost, overriding `paint` of a top level container like `JFrame`.  Lots of reasons, one of which you just found, but also because top level containers are not double buffered, which will introduce flickering when the are painted and `JFrame` contains a bunch of other components, the `JRootPane`, the content pane, the glass pane...all of which could paint over what you are trying to paint.

Also, painting directly to the frame allows you to paint under the frame's decorations, which isn't really what you want to do...

For example (of why it's bad)...

- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)
- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)
- [Java AWT drawString() does not display on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499375/java-awt-drawstring-does-not-display-on-window/17499425#17499425)

## The solution...

Create a custom class extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there.  You gain double buffering support for free and no longer have to worry about the frame's borders, as the content pane will ensure that it's maintained with inside the frame decorations.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Also, call `setResizable` before setting the size of the frame, this changes the size of the frames decorations and can produce unexpected additional spacing within the frames content area...