# JMenuBar Opens In Separate Window from Application

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Working on a Java application that opens a window and allows the user to draw on the window, like a canvas.

I've just added a `JMenuBar` that is going to eventually allow the user to use different drawing tools. The issue is that the `JMenuBar` opens in a separate window from the "canvas" window, and I want the `JMenuBar` to be a part of the same window.

How do I work around this and get this to happen?

This is the method that creates the menu bar:

```
// Create JFrame with MenuBar Components
public static void initializeMenu() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    // JMenu Bar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    // JMenu
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(editMenu);

    // JMenu Items
    jItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    fileMenu.add(jItem);

    // Make JMenuBar Visible in Application
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

And the main method:

```
// Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setSize(800, 500);
        paint.setVisible(true);
        paint.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        initializeMenu();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning an instance of `JMenuBar` from the `initializeMenu` and apply it to the `Paint` class

```
public static JMenuBar initializeMenu() {
    // JMenu Bar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    // JMenu
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(editMenu);

    // JMenu Items
    jItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    fileMenu.add(jItem);

    return menuBar;    
}
```

Then apply it yo the `Paint` class...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setJMenuBar(initializeMenu());        
            paint.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            paint.setSize(800, 500);
            paint.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Personally, I'd favour `pack` over `setSize`, it will generally result in a viewable area which will meet your needs (assuming you're using the layout management API properly)

**Updated...**

You've broken the paint chain

```
public class Paint extends JFrame implements ... {

    //...

    // Method for different drawing stencils
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (p != null) {
            g.setColor(c);
            switch (shapeType) {
                case 0:
                    g.drawOval(p.x - w / 2, p.y - h / 2, w, h);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    g.drawRect(p.x - w / 2, p.y - h / 2, w, h);
                    break;

            }

        }

        // Resets application window surface to white (clears the canvas)
        if (Refresh == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 1500);

        }
        g.drawImage(key, 0, 0, this);

        if (widthincrease == true) {
            w += 1;
        }
        if (heightincrease == true) {
            h += 1;
        }
        if (widthdecrease == true) {
            w -= 1;

            if (w < 1) {
                w = 50;
            }
        }

        if (heightdecrease == true) {
            h -= 1;

            if (h < 1) {
                h = 50;
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

Basically, by overriding `paint`, but never calling `super.paint`, you've prevented the frame from ever painting it's content.

First, you should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, this is just one example of way, but `JFrame` has a bunch of other components which reside on top it.

[image: RootPane]

These can (and will) paint over anything you are trying to paint to the frame.

The frame has borders, which are paint within the frames area, by overriding `paint`, you can paint under these borders, see [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Instead, create a custom class that extends from `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, move the rest of the "painting" related to code this class (and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting).

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Avoid `KeyListener`, seriously, it's just a paint, instead, use the key bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: OK. That makes sense. My Paint class extends Frame though. So, I get the error `The method setMenuBar(JMenuBar) is undefined for the type Paint` so I extended JFrame and the error was fixed, though I cannot see the JMenuBar in the application window still. Should I post the rest of my code?

Comment: Well, then you have a problem.  You can't mix `Swing` and AWT this way.  In fact, based on you comments in your question, I would strong advise against using `java.awt.Canvas` and instance use a `JPanel`, that way, you could extend `Paint` from `JFrame` and solve your problems...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Oh. I'm not using `java.awt.Canvas`, I'm simply saying that the window is like a canvas.

Comment: @Freddie_V4 Going to need to see more code to know why the menubar isn't visible...

Comment: OK. Great. I will take a look at all of the docs you've given me and will get this to work! Thank you